# Export Schedules from Revit Model using Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have found a plug-in to manually export schedules (rebar, production bom, material lists) from Revit models.  However, our company is looking to automate this and take out the human required element of exporting these schedules.

I have not, so far, found a way in the Forge API (Revit Design Automation API) to access these schedules like a can with a custom plug in.

Is this support coming or is there a place to vote on this capability?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

The [Forge Design Automation API for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page)  enables you to run the same .NET Revit API code as the Revit.exe executable on the Windows desktop. Therefore, you can probably convert the existing desktop add-in to run within the Forge environment. There is no missing capability, not additional support needed, and no need to vote for anything. The Building Coder has explored and documented how to migrate and convert existing desktop Revit API add-in code to run in the Forge design automation environment in the topic group on [DA4R – Design Automation for Revit](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).

Comment: Thanks.  This helped get me moving in the right direction.  One challenge I have though is ViewSchedule.Export and ViewSchedule.GetTableData is incredibly slow.

Any suggestions on how to make that faster?